# World border in World composition

Tags: unreal-4

A question. In World Composition there is such a border of the world. As I understand it, everything that goes beyond its limits is destroyed, but is there an option to evade it?
[image]

Comment: [There are good reasons to keep your world content close to the origin when using floating point coordinates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75540/39518) - [going outside this range can result in unsightly artifacts or glitches](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/163940/39518). Games with immense worlds often swap you from one zone with one origin to a new zone with a different origin, so nothing is ever too far from that center point.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for the explanation. As I understand it is necessary to implement the transition to a new level when approaching this border. I'll think about how to do it normally.