# How to keep building map beyond world border / increase map size in Unreal 3?

Tags: unreal

I'm trying to build a huge map in Unreal 3, but I can't move or build in editor because I'm outside the world border, and I can't seem to extend the map size.

I'm looking for a way to increase the map size so I can continue to use the editor.

- I've searched for the `max_world` constant in the development folder.
- I've increased Perspective Grid Size in `EditorComponent.Uc`.
- I changed map size to the increased perspective grid size.

I'm trying to change the world size for Unreal Engine's default `dm_deck` map or whatever the original name is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where in that wall of text is the actual question?

Comment: im asking the statement thats in the question. the editor gets stuck because the world is being built beyond the levels boundaries. some of the information is asundry but its everything I did in trying to fix the problem but not being able to solve it. the details don't change the question. in any case im currently making the world by just building in areas that arent the world boundary.

Comment: but fair enough maybe the question is vague

Comment: Usually when an engine enforces a maximum size limit, [there's a good reason for it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/163936/39518). Typically large/open world games solve this by not having the whole huge world existing statically in a single map.  Instead they break their maps into chunks, loading ones near the player and unloading ones farther away, and [teleporting the player back toward the world origin/re-centering the loaded chunks to keep them from straying too far](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75537/whats-the-largest-relative-level-i-can-make-using-float).

Comment: well partially one of the reasons I wanted to use unreal engine 3 is that computers are so well optimized for that engine today that you could essentially do things highly inefficiently and all youd really need to play your game is 8gb of ram. I paired things back substantially. it takes 15 minutes to traverse the map now. it was originally going to take 30 but I got lazy. the game is a ripoff of unreal tournament 3 but the map attached to it is very large. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fop0Nm37UuM basically breaking its limitations is why i want to use it.